Trigger aws lambda from multiple sources
I want to have one lambda function tat can be triggered by multiple sources

When I upload an xml document in S3 bucket
Via APIGateway request

I tried the following
public class MultiTriggerLambda implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

private final AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();

@Override
public Object handleRequest(Object event, Context context) {
    if (event instanceof S3Event) {
        // S3 Trigger
        return handleS3Event((S3Event) event, context);
    } else if (event instanceof APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent) {
        // API Gateway Trigger
        return handleApiGatewayRequest((APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent) event, context);
    } else {
        // Unknown Event
        return "Unknown event source";
    }
}

The issue is the event coming from S3 is not an instance of S3Event but its a map.
Can I somehow configure my lambda or S3 event so that I get the event as of type S3Event and APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent and not Map?
Thanks

Write multiple function handlers in the same source code, each with a different method signature, then configure each event to trigger the relevant handler. You can make your multiple handlers lightweight and make use of other common code to process the events in a common way.
